# Is there a way of setting "!important" for event.stop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click, alert

I have a script that does `event.stop()` and displays an alert on links.

Some of these links have other `JS` scripts linked to them, like tabs, accordions and so forth.

Of course my `event.stop()` doesn't always fire on them (the alert shows but the tabs etc. still work).

The project is quite big (many different plugins and JSes) and I'm wondering what's the best way of making my `event.stop()` always work before the other scripts do? Something like CSS !important.

Callbacks? For so many scripts?

Comment: From the fact you're using `event.stop`, I take it you're using PrototypeJS? Rather than jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation() like below:

```
$(selector).on('click',function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Not: event.stop  !

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question whether you're using PrototypeJS (which adds a `stop` method to events), or jQuery (which you've tagged, but which *doesn't* add a `stop` method on events).

But it doesn't really matter much to the answer: If the other handlers are attached to the element *before* yours is, there's no way for you to selectively prevent them being fired. You can remove them entirely (it may be hard or easy, but it's possible), but you can't stop them being fired.

If they're attached *after* your handler, then it's easy: Use `Event#stopImmediatePropagation`. jQuery adds it to event objects if the browser doesn't supply it; I don't recall whether PrototypeJS (which hasn't been updated in years) polyfills it for older IE or not. It does some of the others, but I don't know about that one.